# Making an Android App (Java) 'Wait' Until Something Finishes

Tags: java, android, android-intent, wait, resume

I have this app that originally has you take a picture, shows you a progress bar, and uploads it to a website.

What I want to add is something so that before the progress bar shows, an Intent starts an activity that loads a layout with a dropdown menu that allows you to choose a descriptor for the picture.  Following this, once you hit the 'OK' button on this new layout, the program should return back to where it had left off and display the progress bar.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

It seems that all I really want is some way to tell the program to stall for a while to call an intent, and when the user hits 'OK', the code may resume.

Comment: It seems to me you should find `startActivityForResult(...)` useful. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)

Comment: My code is already in an OnActivityResult method, unless what you posted here is entirely separate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should be using OnActivityResult().. More information on the link below  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)

Comment: The code is in an OnActivityResult() method already.  Is there a way I can have this code stall though?  Can I make use of something like OnPause() and OnResume()?

Comment: Why you want to stall, you should display progress bar in onActivityResult() callback.

Comment: Yes, thats how its already set up.  But before that I want it to display a different layout until I'm done with that layout, then jump back to where it left off.

Comment: Sorry Mike but I need some more explanation, what different layout you want to display?

Comment: Well, a camera activity is started.  The user takes a picture and hits OK when they like the picture.  Originally, after hitting OK, you were brought back to the app's main screen.  What I'm trying to do is insert another layout inbetween the camera-picture-taking layout and the return to the main layout, in which the user selects from a Spinner (drop-down menu) a way to describe their picture first.